# Parsing output of the groupBy function JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a large JSON array that contains date, value and volume. Example:

```
{date: "2020-01-16", value: 156884979143.65558, volume: 8637.132542285019},
{date: "2020-01-16", value: 158499951883.22903, volume: 8725.85095973539},
{date: "2020-01-16", value: 157854014765.24777, volume: 8690.254493025197},
{date: "2020-01-17", value: 158412991117.64667, volume: 8720.91950137424},
{date: "2020-01-17", value: 157520921975.09222, volume: 8674.797501545712},
{date: "2020-01-17", value: 158196104624.54498, volume: 8708.907594483513}
```

I want to find the minimum and maximum values for each date. I was able to use groupBy this way:

```
    const groupBy = (array, key) => {
        return array.reduce((result, currentValue) => {
            (result[currentValue[key]] = result[currentValue[key]] || []).push(
            currentValue
            );
            return result;
        }, {}); 
    };    
    var group = groupBy(chartData, 'date');
    console.log(group);
```

to produce something like this:

```
2020-01-16:
{date: "2020-01-16", value: 156884979143.65558, volume: 8637.132542285019},
{date: "2020-01-16", value: 158499951883.22903, volume: 8725.85095973539},
{date: "2020-01-16", value: 157854014765.24777, volume: 8690.254493025197}

2020-01-17:
{date: "2020-01-17", value: 158412991117.64667, volume: 8720.91950137424},
{date: "2020-01-17", value: 157520921975.09222, volume: 8674.797501545712},
{date: "2020-01-17", value: 158196104624.54498, volume: 8708.907594483513}
```

The problem I'm running into now is that to my understanding the output is now an object, no longer a JSON array. Does anyone know how I could go about parsing this output to find the min and max values or a better way to go about accomplishing this? Appreciate any help in advance!

Comment: What is your desired output? A string signifying the dates or keep it as a JSON Array?

Comment: an object or json array is the same thing, you can traverse it, so what's the problem ?

Comment: @tomerpacific I would like to keep it as a JSON array and build a new JSON array using the calculated values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) method to return an array of a given object's own enumerable string-keyed property and [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method to get `max` and `min` values:

```
const maxValues = Object.entries(group).reduce((a, [k, v]) => {
    a[k] = v.reduce((prev, current) => (prev.value > current.value) ? prev : current);
    return a;
}, {})

const minValues = Object.entries(group).reduce((a, [k, v]) => {
    a[k] = v.reduce((prev, current) => (prev.value < current.value) ? prev : current);
    return a;
}, {})
```

An example:

```js
let chartData = [
{ date: "2020-01-16", value: 156884979143.65558, volume: 8637.132542285019 },
{ date: "2020-01-16", value: 158499951883.22903, volume: 8725.85095973539 },
{ date: "2020-01-16", value: 157854014765.24777, volume: 8690.254493025197 },
{ date: "2020-01-17", value: 158412991117.64667, volume: 8720.91950137424 },
{ date: "2020-01-17", value: 157520921975.09222, volume: 8674.797501545712 },
{ date: "2020-01-17", value: 158196104624.54498, volume: 8708.907594483513 }
]

const groupBy = (array, key) => {
  return array.reduce((result, currentValue) => {
      (result[currentValue[key]] = result[currentValue[key]] || []).push(
      currentValue
      );
      return result;
  }, {});
};
let group = groupBy(chartData, 'date');

const maxValues = Object.entries(group).reduce((a, [k, v]) => {
    a[k] = v.reduce((prev, current) => (prev.value > current.value) ? prev : current);
    return a;
}, {})

const minValues = Object.entries(group).reduce((a, [k, v]) => {
    a[k] = v.reduce((prev, current) => (prev.value < current.value) ? prev : current);
    return a;
}, {})


console.log(`group: `, group);
console.log(`maxValues: `, maxValues);
console.log(`minValues: `, minValues);
```

Comment: This solution is very close but it appears to be outputting the last index for both the min and max. This is definitely a step in the right direction though. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @RyanBrown I am glad that it helped to you!:)